# How to write to a TextView from outside a button or onCreate

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

OK,time for another noobie question:

I have declared a TextView at the top of the Activity class as static which I believe should make it "global". Then in onCreate I attach that variable to a TextView. Looks like so:

```
public class CheckerActivity extends Activity {

String testNumber = "0";
public static TextView displayArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);

    int[] numbersArray;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    numbersArray = intent.getIntArrayExtra(EnterCurrentNumbersActivity.CURRENT_NUMBERS_ARRAY);
    String arrayStringed = Arrays.toString(numbersArray);
    displayArray = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentNumbers);
    displayArray.setText(arrayStringed);
}
```

Then in a method I created myself in the same class I'm trying to use that TextView declaration and write something to it. Like so:

```
public void addNumber(String[] numbersToAdd) {

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);

    displayArray.setText(Arrays.toString(numbersToAdd));
}
```

I then have a button that calls the addNumber method like so:

```
public void populateButton(View view) {

        String[] temp = {"test", "array"};
        CheckerActivity addNumbers = new CheckerActivity();
        addNumbers.addNumber(temp);
}
```

But when the button is clicked I keep getting NullPointerException on the addNumber method.

I've searched all over for this but I think I just don't know what to ask Google. As far as I can tell, this should work, where am I going wrong??

logcat after your sugestions. (But Eldar Mensutov got it. Works now!)

`07-09 15:49:48.542  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:49:48.542  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker.CheckerActivity.addNumber(CheckerActivity.java:85)
07-09 15:49:48.542  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker.CheckerActivity.populateButton(CheckerActivity.java:37)
07-09 15:49:48.542  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-09 15:49:48.552  21036-21036/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

To carry of from this question, I now wish to call 
    `public void addNumber(String[] numbersToAdd)`
from a completely different class (whole different file within the same project)
Using `this.addNumber(temp);` doesn't work.
Any suggestions??

Comment: First do not re set "this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);" in addNumber method.and post your logcat.

Comment: i think you miss to button findViewById().

Comment: You don't need `this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);` and remove static from textview.

Comment: Why these methods are public?? Do you access them from outside? If yes then don't do. `CheckerActivity addNumbers = new CheckerActivity();` you can not do this.

Comment: OK, removed `this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);` and static from TextView. logcat is:

Comment: Whats the best way to post logcat? It's too long for this comment... Still getting the NullPointerException by the way.

Comment: @Ash post it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);
```

in your `public void addNumber(String[] numbersToAdd)`.

And replase

```
   CheckerActivity addNumbers = new CheckerActivity();
   addNumbers.addNumber(temp);
```

on

```
   this.addNumber(temp);
```

And make you field not static:    `public TextView displayArray;`

Comment: Thanks Eldar. It was the this.addNumber(temp); that did it!

Comment: Any suggestions on if I wanted to call addNumbers from a completely different class?

Comment: In which kind of class you wanna call method "addNumber(..)"?If it will be another activity you can't do it. If it is not a child of activity class you can put reference of your activity in constructor of your 'completely different class'. Anyway, try it , and ask new question if something goes wrong.

Comment: I'm calling it from a public class that `extends Activity`

Comment: New activity - new layout. One TextView can't belong to two or more activity